# How can I use a class or a ViewModel as the datasource for a ListView with DataTemplate that will show in Design View without compilation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, styles

I am trying to quickly style a DataGrid with DataTemplates and instead of relying on a compiled runtime DataSource, I want to quickly create a DataSource that can be used as the ItemsSource of my ListView to quickly edit the Styling.

C# Code

```
    public class SampleViewModel
{
    #region fields
    private ObservableCollection<DATA> datas;
    #endregion fields

    #region properties
    public ObservableCollection<DATA> DATAs { get { return this.datas; } }
    #endregion properties

    #region constructors
    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        // Establish the invariant of owning a collection of BookSku.
        this.datas = new ObservableCollection<DATA>();

        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            DataSource.LoadSampleDATAs(ref this.datas);
        }
        else
        {
            DataSource.LoadSampleDATAsfromCloud(ref this.datas);
        }
    }
    #endregion constructors
}

public class DATA
{
    #region properties
    public DateTime Date { get; internal set; }
    public string ProvNum { get; internal set; }
    public decimal Fees { get; internal set; }
    #endregion properties
}

internal static class DataSource
{
    #region methods
    public static void LoadSampleDATAs(ref ObservableCollection<DATA> datas)
    {
        datas.Add(new DATA()
        {
            Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
            ProvNum = "1",
            Fees = (decimal)150
        });
        datas.Add(new DATA()
        {
            Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2),
            ProvNum = "2",
            Fees = (decimal)250
        });
    }

    public static void LoadSampleDATAsfromCloud(ref ObservableCollection<DATA> datas)
    {
        // In this simple app, we'll simulate real-world data access by loading sample data.
        DataSource.LoadSampleDATAs(ref datas);
    }
    #endregion methods
}
```

XAML Code

```
<Page.DataContext>
        <services:SampleViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DATAs}"/>
```

The Binding works at runtime but still does not work in design view and the Grid Shows up but doesn't show the Items. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Microsoft docs may help you despite they suggest a different way: [Use Design Time Data with the XAML Designer in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2019) I understand you want the design-time data in the view and not holding on to data source as a class.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work in Design Mode - it is extremely cumbersome to style controls in runtime as it throws an unhandled exception every time a style is changed. I updated the implemented code above - am I doing something wrong?